# What is the best way to setup wordpress development environment for freelancers with version control?

Tags: multisite, version-control

I am trying to setup wordpress development environment for freelancers. I have freelancers working on my site from different locations. Which tools and technologies will support development of my current website and how?

I came across vagrant, will it be useful? Also, how can I do version control?

I have decided to go with sub-domain development environment, as I am not expecting my freelancers to install whole website on local. Our website is too big with multisite setup, we have three teams at different location, one for design and other two for development. Also we are expanding our team now and then. So installing on local would not be suitable. I am going to use git and bitbucket. Can I create my master git repository directly from sub-domain development environment? How git setup would be ideally? Where should be my master repository and how many branches I should create?

Comment: this is not a wordpress specific question. maybe this is not the best place to ask it.

Answer (score 0):

I specially suggest wpengine If you are not much familiar with Vigrant Or Other version control software. Wpengine internally uses git version controlling mechanisam.

Wpengine has very easy UI & not technical person can also manage it. It has inbuilt staging environment as well as other stuff that matches with your requirement. It is paid but not so costly. It has good support also.

you can perform task like create staging site on single click.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at VVV ?

Varying Vagrant Vagrants is designed to support WordPress plugin and theme development using vagrant boxes and github version control.

https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV

Re Github/Bitbucket - you may possibly use one master and then have a branch per subdomain if there is enough commonality, but from the very vague information you have provided it looks like one master per subdomain would be more sensible.  That way development would not overlap.

I won't paste the whole VVV front page here, but just a bit to get you started:

***Overview***

**The Purpose of Varying Vagrant Vagrants**

The primary goal of Varying Vagrant Vagrants (VVV) is to provide an approachable development environment with a server configuration common for high traffic WordPress sites.

VVV is ideal for developing themes and plugins as well as for contributing to WordPress core.